# Append Blob not concatenating pdf pages correctly

Tags: node.js, azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Storage to store some pdfs as blobs. I want to concatenate them on the fly using the [`AppendBlob class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/appendblobclient?view=azure-node-latest) that is offered in the Node SDK for Azure Storage. My problem is that even though the merged pdf is the correct size, when I open it, it only shows the last page in it, instead of all the pages that I concatenate. Am I making a mistake in the code? I would appreciate any insight into the problem.

I don't want to have to download them and concatenate them in code because in certain cases the resultant pdf exceeds 2gb in size and node cant handle that.

```
    let bundleUuid = uuidv4();
    var connString = process.env.ST_ENV_01_APS_03_CONNECTION_STRING;
    var appendBlobClient = new AppendBlobClient(connString, container, userId + "/bundles/" + bundleUuid + ".pdf");
    await appendBlobClient.create();
    context.log(userId + "/bundles/" + bundleUuid + ".pdf");
    
    for (const basketDocumentUri of basketDocumentUris) {
        
        context.log("Fetching: " + basketDocumentUri.document_uuid + "/" + (basketDocumentUri.page_index + 1) + ".pdf")
       
        let bbc = await containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(basketDocumentUri.document_uuid 
            + "/" + (basketDocumentUri.page_index + 1) + ".pdf");
        let details = await bbc.getProperties();
        let url = self.generateSasTokenPDF(basketDocumentUri.document_uuid + "/"
         + (basketDocumentUri.page_index + 1) + ".pdf", "r");
       
        try { 
            
            let mbblk = 4194304
            let offset = 0;
            while(offset < details.contentLength){

                let response = await appendBlobClient.appendBlockFromURL(url.uri,offset,mbblk);
                context.log(response);
                
                offset += mbblk;
                
                context.log(offset);
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            context.log(error);
            debugger;
        }
    }
    callback(bundleUuid)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach would work. Essentially PDF file is a binary file with a pre-defined format. In an append blob, you are simply appending the bytes to an existing blob and this would make the format of the PDF file invalid.

Comment: the resultant pdf seems to be valid, because it opens fine, the only issue is that it only retains the last page added in.

Comment: I'm sorry if you consider my comment rude. All i wanted to express is that i was surprised that you considered it fine that the viewer displayed something different than expected.

Comment: On the issue at hand: as @Gaurav already hinted at, concatenation of multiple pdf files does *not* result in a single valid pdf containing all the pages. Instead, it is invalid as a pdf. Note, though, that pdf viewers notoriously attempt to repair broken pdfs. Thus, your viewer attempted to repair your file which resulted in it showing you one page only.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav said in the comment, *simply appending the bytes to an existing blob would make the format of the PDF file invalid*. It's **not possible** to interact with the files without downloading them somewhere.

Following is download blob to Buffer:

```
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  // Get blob content from position 0 to the end
  // In Node.js, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody
  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
  const downloaded = (
    await streamToBuffer(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
  ).toString();
  console.log("Downloaded blob content:", downloaded);

  // [Node.js only] A helper method used to read a Node.js readable stream into a Buffer
  async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
        chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
      });
      readableStream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });
      readableStream.on("error", reject);
    });
  }
```

Using HummusJS to combine PDFs:

```
const hummus = require('hummus');
const memoryStreams = require('memory-streams');

/**
 * Concatenate two PDFs in Buffers
 * @param {Buffer} firstBuffer 
 * @param {Buffer} secondBuffer 
 * @returns {Buffer} - a Buffer containing the concactenated PDFs
 */
const combinePDFBuffers = (firstBuffer, secondBuffer) => {
    var outStream = new memoryStreams.WritableStream();

    try {
        var firstPDFStream = new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(firstBuffer);
        var secondPDFStream = new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(secondBuffer);

        var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify(firstPDFStream, new hummus.PDFStreamForResponse(outStream));
        pdfWriter.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(secondPDFStream);
        pdfWriter.end();
        var newBuffer = outStream.toBuffer();
        outStream.end();

        return newBuffer;
    }
    catch(e){
        outStream.end();
        throw new Error('Error during PDF combination: ' + e.message);
    }
};

combinePDFBuffers(PDFBuffer1, PDFBuffer2);
```

Comment: we already have such a solution implemented, we were looking to use AppendBlob or some other trick to get around memory constraints, as at times we end up working with pdfs >500 MB in size which we cannot convert to buffers and store in variables to manipulate